# SSRS Report Builder Tablix not displaying dataset results but dataset/query returns results

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

On SSRS/Report Builder I have written a dataset/query and this returns results.   However, when I create a tablix to display results of this dataset/query the tablix just displays the column headers.  The rows do not display results.  What do I need to check?   Any recommendations?

Not sure if this is a factor:  my dataset combines data from 2 databases. i.e;

```
    SELECT t1.BookingNumber, t2.ReceiptNumber 
      FROM DatabaseA.dbo.Bookings AS t1 
 LEFT JOIN DatabaseB.dbo.Receipts AS t2 ON t1.BookingsPKey = t2.BookingsFKey
```

It is when I try to display results of this query on a tablix that I hit this issue.

However, when I get data only from one database, i.e;

```
SELECT t1.BookingNumber 
  FROM DatabaseA.dbo.Bookings
```

and attempt to display it on a tablix there are no issues displaying the results.

Comment: Have you tried uploading it to the server, and running it live?  Occasionally report builder can get in a tiz, and not display results correctly.  Try that first and see.

Comment: If you're running into the problem @bushell mentions, you can also either re-run the dataset with new parameters, or delete the *.rdl.data files in your project directory - these are the files that cache report data during development so that Visual Studio doesn't have to fetch it from the server every time you want to test a formatting tweak.

Comment: Thanks bushell I shall try that out.  If that doesn't run I shall try out kyzen's recommendation (delete the *.rdl data files).  Will see how that goes.